# Loop in elements of Array dynamically based on logic using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2010, excel-2007

I am writing a piece of code to pick the current and nextquarter values using Arrays concept in VBA.
However i am facing runtime error 13 when running the below code.

```
Sub PlaceTheQuarter()
Dim arr, Q1, Q2, Q3, Q4

arr = Array(1, "Q1", 2, "Q2", 3, "Q3", 4, "Q4")
Q1 = Array("Jan", "Feb", "Mar")
Q2 = Array("Apr", "May", "Jun")
Q3 = Array("Jul", "Aug", "Sep")
Q4 = Array("Oct", "Nov", "Dec")

'MsgBox (Application.Match(Application.RoundUp(Month(Date) / 3, 0)))
MsgBox (arr(Application.Match(Application.RoundUp(Month(Date) / 3, 0), arr, 0)))

'ENABLE THIS PART TO TEST Q4 ITERATION
Dim idate As Date
idate = "31-DEC-2020"
a = arr(Application.Match(Application.RoundUp(Month(idate) / 3, 0), arr, 0))

'a = arr(Application.Match(Application.RoundUp(Month(Date) / 3, 0), arr, 0))
i = Mid(a, 2, 1)

Dim next_q As Integer

If i = 4 Then
 next_q = 1
Else
 next_q = i + 1
End If

MsgBox ("Next Quarter is: Q" & next_q)

MsgBox (MonthName(Month(idate), True))
counter = 0

Dim n_quarter
n_quarter = "Q" & next_q

    For Each ab In Q4
        If MonthName(Month(idate), True) = ab Then
            MsgBox ab
            Dim pos As Integer
            pos = Application.Match(ab, Q4, False)
            MsgBox pos
        Else
        End If
    Next


End Sub
```

Basically in the Foreach loop if i use the quarter name manually as Q4 it loops in fine.But i would like to pass it dynamically based on values like `Q&next_q` ..I've assigned a string value and passed that variable here which isn't either working in my case.

Any pointers on this is much appreciated...

My intention is to get the corresponding quarter array looped in as the date progresses in a year.

Comment: Could you describe what the code is supposed to do? Best add the description to your post.

Comment: Basically if you consider the last for loop I am trying to find the occurrence of or index of month from array..but the code is hardcoded for test..since the test worked fine.i would like to get the loop of elements in particular quarter to be picked.ex: jan q1, Jun q2 etc.

Comment: I was more thinking of if you are writing a function then, will return the quarter for a date or an array of quarters for an array of dates or what? Or if you're writing a sub what will it do?

Comment: Thank you for your response.Basically the sub is trying to find the current and next quarter number...and the intention of creating the `ForEach` loop is to find the index number of the current month in the corresponding Quarter array and later on i would be adding some extra code to fulfil my other requirements of automation...I would currently like to call the ForEach loop dynamically for the corresponding Quarter as the dates progress in a year..Please advise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, test the next code. It should act as (I understood) you requested in the last comment:

```
Sub PlaceTheQuarter()
 Dim arr, arrQ, Q1, Q2, Q3, Q4, ab, a As String, i As Long, k As Long
 Dim next_q As Long, next_month As Long, arrFin, j As Long, actQ As Long
 
 arr = Array(1, "Q1", 2, "Q2", 3, "Q3", 4, "Q4")
 Q1 = Array("Jan", "Feb", "Mar")
 Q2 = Array("Apr", "May", "Jun")
 Q3 = Array("Jul", "Aug", "Sep")
 Q4 = Array("Oct", "Nov", "Dec")
 arrQ = Array(Q1, Q2, Q3, Q4)

 Dim idate As Date: idate = Date '"02.10.2021"

 a = arr(Application.match(Application.RoundUp(Month(idate) / 3, 0), arr, 0))

 Select Case a
    Case "Q1": next_month = Month(idate): actQ = 0
    Case "Q2": next_month = Month(idate) - 3: actQ = 1
    Case "Q3": next_month = Month(idate) - 6: actQ = 2
    Case "Q4": next_month = Month(idate) - 9: actQ = 3
 End Select
 
 ReDim arrFin((3 - next_month) + 2)
 i = Mid(a, 2, 1)

 If i = 4 Then
    next_q = 1
 Else
    next_q = i + 1
 End If
 'fill the final array containing the remained month plus the next quarter months:
 For j = next_month To 2
    arrFin(k) = arrQ(actQ)(j): k = k + 1
 Next j
 For j = 0 To 2
    arrFin(k) = arrQ(next_q - 1)(j): k = k + 1
 Next j
 '______________________________________________________
 'Iterate between the necessary array elements:
 For Each ab In arrFin
    Debug.Print ab
 Next
End Sub
```

Comment: hi @FaneDuru, i could get the logic behind this Jagged array usage..Thanks for that..However,i am still facing issue in finding the index value that i was expecting in my case to built further logic.Any adivse?

Comment: @user2075017: "i am still facing issue in finding the index value" is not something to tell me too much, in order to be able to advice... Please, explain what does not work as you need, You only said that "But i would like to pass it dynamically based on values like `Q&next_q`" and this is what i tried to solve...

Comment: I get you.so if I run macro today the for each loop should run for Q1 and tell me index of Jan as 1..if I run it someday in Dec it should loop the foreach loop for Q4 and index value should be 3..my main objective is to pick current and rest of months of current quarter and months from next quarter which is easy once the dynamic pick of quarter number happens and I am looking for help in this. Apols if I was confusing earlier.

Comment: @user2075017:OK. I will edit the above answer and post your adapted code, able to retrieve the month of the next quarter, against the current date.

Comment: @user2075017: Didn't you find some time to test the above (second) code? If tested, doesn't do it what you need? If not, please better explain what you really want accomplishing.

Comment: Hi @FaneDuru ,i have tested the piece of code but that didnt give my result.Actually..here is what i am trying to get...if i run the macro today (`19-JAN-2021`) i would like to get the current quarter pending months and next quarter months listed out..my output today should be `FEB,MAR,APR,MAY,JUN` ..However if i run this on `01-MAR-2021` i should get output as `APR,MAY,JUN` (as Mar is last month of quarter and no pending months are available in Q1)The main reason for capturing the `index` number of current month of date is to pull values from  `index+1`.Please advise.

Comment: @@user2075017: You did not ask for such a think in your question, at least I couldn't understand it... I only tried adapting your code to return what it looks trying. But OK, I will prepare a piece of code to do what I understood (now) you need. Not right now, but in less than an hour...

Comment: hi @FaneDuru, Apols i may not have asked this question in initial query as the query i had asked is interlinked to the logic in selecting the quarter array dynamically which i had thought of..However,i would be grateful to you if you can prepare code for me..

Comment: @user2075017: Please, test the updated code and send some feedback.

Comment: Thanks alot for your help..This does it all what i needed..

Comment: @user2075017: Glad I could help!